# How to make desktop wallpaper private in video call?

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop

I use my pc for gaming and work,
I used two different accounts in windows but it's a lot of hassle when installing a program or setting up networks.

Is there any way to make the wallpaper of the desktop private?
I'm not asking for specific program, like Microsoft teams or teamviewer.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is to use virtual desktops. This will help you use one user account, but have two (or more) desktops (and wallpapers) so you can select one depend of purpose: working or gaming.

Comment: Oh, wow, I didn't know I can do that, thanks a lottt